# Panel border properties in ggplot2's themes

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

Consider this simple plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
ggsave("testFig.pdf")
```

If I now open it in Adobe Illustrator and I select the panel border with the Direct Selection Tool I can see that this border has no color, no fill and no stroke weight (see below) even though they are specified within `theme_bw()`.

[image]

If I now delete this "object" within Illustrator the correct panel border finally appears. You can see in the image here below that the panel border has now the fill, color and stroke weight which are specified in `theme_bw()`. If you compare the stroke weight in the two images you'll also note that the stroke weight was not correct in the first image, it was too thin.

[image]

How do I specify within `ggplot2`'s theme that I don't want this "object" in my plots?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a clipping rectangle, as illustrated by

```
library(ggplot2)
p = qplot(1,1, size=I(200)) + theme_bw() 
ggsave("testFig.pdf", p)
```

(removing the rectangle makes the big dot extend over the top and bottom)

This suggests a way to get rid off it, although it may have unwanted consequences,

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
g$layout$clip <- "off"
ggsave("testFig.pdf", g)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But, it should be possible to build the plot in such a way that the clipping rectangle is behind the layer that contains the panel border, isn't it? If so, should this be filed as a small bug?